# How do i confirm intern is installed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, functional-testing, intern

As I installed the intern locally by command

```
npm install intern --save-dev
```

And globally by command

```
npm install -g intern
```

It seems that the intern is installed but how do I confirm it?
As I run the command `intern --version`, the error message said

> intern is not recognized as internal or external command

How do I confirm that `intern` is installed successfully?.

Comment: Prathik, It seems but I am not sure, If it's installed then `intern --version` display the version, right?

Comment: I'll be glad, If the down-voter would provide the link.

Comment: I meant provide the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Intern's bin scripts are called `intern-runner` and `intern-client`. If you have installed Intern globally, you should be able to run either of those directly; doing so should print an error message indicating that Intern needs a config. If you have installed Intern locally to your project, you'll either need to add "./node_modules/.bin" to your PATH, or run intern as `./node_modules/.bin/intern-{runner,client}`

Intern does not support a `--version` flag. Check out [the documentation](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#node-client) for more information about supported arguments.

Comment: I installed `intern` globally, error message shows the Intern needs to be config, now what should I do after this?

Comment: Okay globally I could run this command something like `intern-client config=tests/intern`, but how can I run this command locally in window7? If I do something like `./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern` then the error message shows `.` is not internal or external command.

Comment: In Windows, paths are separated by '\', so you'd run `node_modules\.bin\intern-client config=tests/intern`. Note that the argument for `config` is a module ID, not a path, so it still uses forward slashes.